# Error: cannot find a working diff3 library program

Tags: aix, rcs

While compiling `rcs` on AIX I got the following error:

```
# ./configure
creating cache ./config.cache
checking diff basename... diff
checking for diff... /usr/bin/diff
checking diff success status... 0
checking diff failure status... 1
checking diff trouble status... 2
checking diff options for RCS... -n
checking diff -L... no
checking diff3 -m... no
checking diff3 library program... configure: error: cannot find a working diff3 library program
```

Comment: could you provide `which diff3` output?

Comment: @MustafaDOGRU: I put the answer to your question in my answer.  I will delete this comment after a while to avoid clutter.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I did a `which diff3` the program was located here: `/usr/bin/diff3`.

So to fix, I changed this line in `configure`:

```
for i in /usr/*lib*/*diff3*; do
```

to this:

```
for i in /usr/*bin*/*diff3*; do
```

I have not fully tested, but it did compile.